# Invertible operators and K-algebra generated by a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Best Regards.

I have doubts on how to attack this exercise:

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension on a field $\Bbb K$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ a invertible linear operator. Prove that $T^{-1}\in\Bbb K[T]$.

Where $\Bbb K[T]$ is the set defined by $\Bbb K[T]$=$\{p(T)|p(x)\in \Bbb K[x]\}$.

$P(T)$ represents an evaluation of an element of the ring of polynomials $\Bbb K[x]$ in the operator $T$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the characteristic polynomial of $T$ namely $char_T(X)=det(T-XI)$. Then by the Cayley Hamiltonian Theorem we have $char_T(T)=0\in End(V)$. Since $T$ is invertible we have $det(T)=char_T(0)\neq0$. Thus we get a Polynomial of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$ with $a_0=det(A)\neq0$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iT^i=0$  Thus we have $T^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{-a_i}{a_0}T^{i-1}$ which was to be proved.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, the characteristic polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ of $T$ has a nonzero constant term if $T$ is invertible, and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem says $T$ satisfies this polynomial: $\sum_{i=0}^n a_iT^i=0$.

Then rearranging you get $\frac{1}{a_0}(-\sum_{i=1}^n a_iT^{i-1})T=1$ so of course $\frac{1}{a_0}(-\sum_{i=1}^n a_iT^{i-1})=T^{-1}\in\mathbb K[T]$